# Spring Data Solr with Querydsl

Tags: solr, solrj, querydsl, spring-data-solr

Assuming I have a spring-data-jpa model classes annotated with solr annotations and I have generated querydsl classes to it (meaning that I can query spring-data-jpa repositories with querydsl's predicates)...

Is it possible to query Spring-data-solr repositories with Querydsl predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, the Spring Data Solr team has not implemented QueryDSL for their part of the framework.  Here's the relevant JIRA ticket for that:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-260